# want url validation regex

Tags: javascript

when i put https://gmail.com in url validation it will through below exception

```
(Exp:Sorry! You cannot include the intended website in Web Tab, as the
intended website restricts its content from loading inside another
website.)
```

i want that url validate regex

Comment: Were do you get this exception? what are things you tried?? Is it really javascript..

Comment: i used this regex(regex: ^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/|www\.)[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$) but it will allowed https://gmail.com but i need to don't allow https://gmail.com

Comment: Hold on a second; gmail.com is a perfectly valid URI. You may want to do a separate blacklist check after the URI check (to disallow specific URIs)

Comment: if(/https\:\/\/gmail\.com/.test(url)){throw new Error("\(Exp\:Sorry! You cannot include the intended website in Web Tab, as the intended website restricts its content from loading inside another website.\)");}

Answer (score 1):

Please see this gist for a pretty strong regex with explainatory comments https://gist.github.com/dperini/729294

EDIT:
You can customize it by removing the strings you don't want.